# Что значит запустить Spring Boot приложение в контейнере?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

У меня есть Spring Boot приложение. На сервере я запускаю его как:

```
java -jar my_app.war
```

На днях преподаватель сказал запускать приложение в контейнере. Я не могу понять, как это? У Spring Boot и так же есть контейнер.

Что значит запускать приложение в контейнере?

Comment: Собирайте его не в jar файл, а в war и разворачивайте в контейнере сервлетов, например в Tomcat. А вообще, если что-то не понимаете, лучше уточняйте именно у того, кто дает задания

Comment: @RomanDanilov мне что бы уточнить и нужна информация из уст профессионалов. У Boot же есть контейнер. Зачем ему Tomcat?  Или мы о разных вещах говорим?

Comment: почему вы не спросите преподавателя или однокурсников?

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что `SpringBoot` приложение может быть собрано как в `jar` файл, со встроенным контейнером сервлетов (`Tomcat`), так и в `war` файл, который потом можно развернуть в любом другом контейнере сервлетов/сервере приложений (`Tomcat`, `Jetty`, `JBoss` и т.д.)
Есть даже [туториал](http://spring-projects.ru/guides/convert-jar-to-war-maven/)  как упаковать и развернуть`SpringBoot` приложение во внешнем контейнере сервлетов. Собственно вас интересует последняя часть статьи (начиная с "Инициализация сервлета")